# Flexbox items not aligned correctly due to different text size

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a flex container that has some flex items in it.
The flex direction is column and I would like to the elements inside each item be placed correctly under each other.

This is not happening because the h4 text is different in length and thats why the space-between messes up the layout (temperatures).

Any help appreciate it!

HTML

```
<div class="container next-week">
      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Today</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Tuesday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Wednesday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Thursday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Friday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.next-week {
  color: #f1e3d5;

  margin-top: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4rem;
}

.forecast-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.forecast-item h4 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #f1e3d5;
  margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.forecast-item i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.high-low {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fixed width to the "day" class.

```css
.next-week {
  color: #f1e3d5;

  margin-top: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 4rem;
}

.forecast-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.forecast-item h4 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  color: #f1e3d5;
  margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.forecast-item i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.high-low {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.forecast-item .day {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container next-week">
      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Today</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Tuesday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Wednesday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Thursday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="forecast-item">
        <h4 class="day">Friday</h4>
        <div class="high-low">
          <h4 class="high">28&deg;</h4>
          <h4 class="low">21&deg;</h4>
        </div>
        <i class="wi wi-day-cloudy"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so easy but your mind never goes there. Thank you so much!

Comment: Totally understand you. Glad I helped.